# php curl run send proxy ip

Tags: php, curl

i made curl script , my script get blocked after website detects bot.

how can i prvent it ,

i tried below code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$proxy = "10.128.60.40:3128";
// needed to disable SSL checks for this site
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxy");
```

but still my i get data as you are blocked due to automated script,

how can u send dynamic ip to avoid this issue

Answer (score 2):

you should use:

1) Anonimous proxies (dies quick and need to parse them)

OR

2) TOR https://www.torproject.org

OR

3) Be not so active. use sleep(1); in your code

Comment: yeah but see i am using Anonimous proxies but it think it still using my proxy , can u check whats wrong with my code

Comment: i think your code is ok. seems like this proxy have been blackened by your "victim"